# django view create model object

Tags: python, django

my site uses a rating feature where users are able to create a request for a new category, afterwards at least 100 users have to rate on this request, if 100/100 users have rated positiv for this request, the category should get created but i don't know how i can create the category model instance after the rating has reached 100/100 Positive votes.

views.py

```
def category_request_up_vote (request, pk):
    category_request = get_object_or_404(CategoryRequests, pk=pk)
    try:
        if request.method == 'GET':
            if category_request.author == request.user:
                messages.error(request, 'You are trying to vote a request you created by your own. Thats not possible (Transmision ignored).')
                return redirect('category_request_detail', pk=category_request.pk)
            if CategoryRequests_Vote.objects.filter(voter=request.user, voted=category_request).exists():
                messages.error(request, 'You already Voted this request. Double votes are not allowed (Transmision ignored).')
                return redirect('category_request_detail', pk=category_request.pk)
            else:
                if category_request.up_vote == 100:
                    print("So what should i do now?")
                else:
                    category_request.up_vote = F('up_vote') + 1
                    category_request.save()
                    CategoryRequests_Vote.objects.create(voter=request.user, voted=category_request)
                    messages.success(request, 'You have successfully Provided an Up-Vote for this Request.')
                    return redirect('category_request_detail', pk=category_request.pk)
        else:
            messages.error(request, 'Uuups, something went wrong, please try again.')
            return redirect('category_request_detail', pk=category_request.pk)
    except:
        messages.error(request, 'Uuups, something went wrong, please try again.')
        return redirect('category_request_detail', pk=category_request.pk)
```

models.py

```
class Category(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30, verbose_name="Title")
    description = models.TextField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=False)
    cover = fields.ImageField(blank=False,
                              null=False,
                              upload_to=get_file_path_static_glued,
                              validators=[default_image_size, file_extension_category_cover],
                              dependencies=[FileDependency(
                                  processor=ImageProcessor(format='PNG', quality=99, scale={
                                      'max_width': 700, 'max_height': 700}))])

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Category"
        verbose_name_plural = "Categories"
        ordering = ['title']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.post = None
        self.post_sell_multiple = None


    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    @classmethod
    def get_indexable(cls):
        return cls.objects.all()

    @classmethod
    def configure_mapping(cls, mapping):
        # mapping is an elasticsearch_dsl Mapping object
        mapping.field('title', 'string')
        return mapping


class CategoryRequests(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=20, verbose_name="Title")
    description = models.TextField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    cover = fields.ImageField(
                              null=True,
                              blank=True,
                              upload_to=get_file_path_user_uploads,
                              validators=[default_image_size, default_image_file_extension],
                              dependencies=[FileDependency(processor=ImageProcessor(
                                  format='PNG', quality=99, scale={'max_width': 700, 'max_height': 700}))])
    published_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    status = StatusField(default='Waiting')
    STATUS = Choices('Waiting', 'Rejected', 'Accepted')
    up_vote = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    down_vote = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def publish(self):
        self.published_date = timezone.now()
        self.save()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Category Request"
        verbose_name_plural = "Category Request(s)"
        ordering = ['title']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Comment: And yes, its GET instead of POST ;) but this has another background at that point.

Comment: Can you post your CategoryRequests model too?Maybe you can use some data like  a title of catagory requested and do a Category.objects.create() once the votes reaches a 100/100.

Comment: @Sammy J: Done :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CategoryRequest model has the fields that the Category model  requires, such as title, description, etc.

Use simple django ORM for this, inside your `if category_request.up_vote == 100:`
you can write,

`category=Category.objects.create(title=category_request.title,description=category_request.description)` ,

add the other fields that the Category model needs
 and in the next line `category.save()`. So now the category is created.

Comment: Merci Sammy ;) Have a nice weekend.

Comment: Maybe one last question, how do i get the pk of the new created category?

Comment: simple, after category.save() you can get the pk by `category.pk` :)